# Adding more fields to an existing model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have done this:

```
rails generate model User name:string   email: string
```

and also have done this:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

and now I decide to add a third field like address to the User model. How should I do that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do this:

```
  rails g migration AddAddressToUser address:string
  rake db:migrate
```

Comment: do I also need modifying the class too ? as the answer of Marc suggests?

Comment: @BDotA This is essentially a shorthand to what I provided. If you can contain your changes in the command line, go for it, but they give you the same result. Usually you only need to dive into the migration if you want to make a lot of changes or do more complex things that aren't supported by the command line options

Comment: It will create the new class. you don't have to do any modification.

Answer (score 6):

You should create a new migration:

```
rails generate migration AddAddressToUser
```

Then in the migration:

```
class AddAddressToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        add_column :users, :address, :string
    end
end
```

Then run `rake db:migrate` again. I recommend reading up on [Rails Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) and why they are so beneficial to developing with models that change over time.